Business Central API V2 Uploaded Attachment is empty
I create attachments for Business Central, Journal Lines, using the V2 API. The code looks like this:
// Creating a file

const fileData = new FormData()
const fileBlob = new Blob([file.buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' })
fileData.append('file', fileBlob, `${file.name}.pdf`)

// Creating a line

const { data } = await firstValueFrom(
    this.businessCentralHttpService.post<JournalLineModel>(
        `companies(${bcCompanyId})/journals(${journalId})/journalLines`,
        dataToSend, // does not matter - everything works here
    ),
)

// Creating an attachment - also works

const { data: attachment } = await firstValueFrom(
  this.businessCentralHttpService.post<{
    id: string
    parentId: string
  }>(`companies(${bcCompanyId})/attachments`, {
    parentId: data.id,
    fileName: `${file.name}.pdf`,
    parentType: 'Journal',
  }),
)

// This seems to always leave the attachment empty

const response = await firstValueFrom(
  this.businessCentralHttpService.patch(
    `companies(${bcCompanyId})/attachments(${attachment.id})/attachmentContent`,
    fileData,
    {
      headers: {
        'If-Match': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    },
  ),
)

The API Documentation I'm using doesn't mention anything about formdata, but neither it does show an example of how the content needs to be uploaded.
The request for updating the content doesn't fail, returns 204, but the file seems corrupt (empty).

Assuming that fileData essentially stores formData, yes this should indeed work. Can you provide more information about the fileData variable? What does the string you are storing in that variable look like?

I can reproduce this behavior in Postman. When the Content-Type value is default (auto-generated: multipart/form-data; boundary=) the size of the file(s) is 0, as well. When the Content-Type header is unchecked, the content is uploaded. If the Content-Type multipart/form-data is manually inserted, it's also uploaded. So the “: boundary=...” section might be the problem, which makes me wonder since you also added it manually.
Alternatively you can upload a single file with Content-Type application/pdf, which should work for now, until we solved the problem.

@ChristianBraeunlich Thanks for your response! I updated the code to illustrate the part with the file

The file should be correct - tried to write it on disk without a problem


upload a single file with Content-Type application/pdf

Do you mean changing the Content-Type in the code I provided? If yes, I tried it - getting the same result

As we discussed, it seemed that the header ‘Content-Type’: ‘multipart/form-data’ was being ignored for some reason.
A quick rewrite of the code to standard node with fetch solved the problem.
Apparently axios (which is used by HttpService) doesn't work properly with ‘Content-Type’: ‘multipart/form-data’ or perhaps wasn't used as intended. I haven't looked into it further, as the problem was solved by a rewrite.
